# Is there any way to work around an unused type parameter?

Tags: rust, traits, type-parameter

Code:

```
trait Trait<T> {}

struct Struct<U>;

impl<T, U: Trait<T>> Struct<U> {}
```

Error:

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> src/main.rs:5:6
  |
5 | impl<T, U: Trait<T>> Struct<U> {}
  |      ^ unconstrained type parameter
```

It seems that [RFC 447](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/447) prohibits this pattern; is there any way to work around this? I think it could be solved by changing `T` to an associated type, but that would prevent me from doing multidispatch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A type parameter that's unused in the struct can use [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html):

```
struct Struct<U> {
    _marker: PhantomData<U>,
}

impl<U> Struct<U> {
    fn example<T>(&self)
    where
        U: Trait<T>,
    {
        // use `T` and `U`
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it's already possible to use where clause on methods. Rust is really an amazing language.

Comment: If you need to erase type lifetimes in a Drop implementation see: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/dropck.html#an-escape-hatch